# Time needed to solve NIntegrate is much longer than what I was expecting

Tags: numerical-integration, list-manipulation, parallelization

I'm trying to do the following list:

```
tablevdip = 
   ParallelTable[{x, y, Vdip[x, y, 6]}, {x, -1, 1, .5}, {y, -1, 1, .5}];]
```

with

```
Vdip[x_, y_, z_] := 
 1/(4 π ϵ r[x, y, z]^2)
   pdip[r[x, y, z], θ[x, y, z], ϕ[x, y, z]]
```

and

```
pdip[r_, θ_, ϕ_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  r2 Cos[θef[θ, θl, ϕ, ϕl]] ρ[
    r2, θef[θ, θl, ϕ, ϕl], ϕl] \
r2^2 Sin[θef[θ, θl, ϕ, ϕl]], {r2, 0, 
   r}, {θl, 0, π}, {ϕl, 0, 2 π}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 7, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

Problem is, when I just call `Vdip[1,1,6]`, for example, it takes .8 seconds to give the result, but when I call it from the `Table` command, it takes 190 seconds, in what should be ~25 seconds. What the heck is going on?

I didn't write the other variables because I think it would be too much information. If someone need it to figure out my problem, please ask me.

EDIT: some definitions:

```
 θef[θ_, θl_, ϕ_, ϕl_] = ArcCos[Cos[θ] Cos[θl] + Sin[θ] Sin[θl] Cos[ϕ - ϕl]];
ρ[r_, θ_, ϕ_] = ϕ^5;
ϵ = 1;
r[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
ϕ[x_, y_, z_] := If[x == 0 && y == 0, 0, ArcTan[x, y]];
θ[x_, y_, z_] := ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];
```

Comment: What's `r[x,y,z]`, etc?  Spherical coords?  -- Can't say without code.  There are several instances on this site in which `ParallelTable` takes longer than `Table.`  Note that `NIntegrate` may use internally parallelized computation itself.

Comment: Yes, its spherical coordinates. I'll edit with the values of the coordinates. I tried to use Table first, and ParallelTable was faster by a factor of 1.77 (unfortunately my computer has only 2 cores).

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The integrals when one of the coordinates is 1/2 take longer, almost 2 sec.  In all a non-parallelized `Table` takes about 30 sec., which is about right.  Try quitting the kernel and starting from scratch, just in case you have a definition lurking that's interfering with the computation.